# How to validate an oAuth2 token when using Yii2 as a REST API

Tags: rest, oauth-2.0, yii2, adfs

I have a single page app that acts as a CMS (the client) which is served by an API (the resource server) built using Yii2. Logging in is handled via an Active Directory server (the authorization server) that implements oAuth2 with the Authorization Code Grant flow.

Basically when the user hits the CMS the CMS handles the user logging in and exchanges the code for the bearer token which is then passed to the API in the headers of the request. The API does not handle any of the logging in or exchanging the code for the token, so all it needs to do is verify that the token is valid.

I'm trying to do this with Yii2 though I'm running into some confusion since from what I can tell this method isn't really how Yii2 is set up to deal with. Our resource server really has no idea of users (there is no user table in our database) as the point is for that to be all handled via Active Directory. Is there a way for me to handle the validation of the token writing a custom authclient (extending yii\authclient\OAuth2) or do I need to come up with some completely custom way to handle this?

In \app\config\web.php I have added the following to components part of the config:

```
'authClientCollection' => [
    'class' => 'yii\authclient\Collection'
    'clients' => [
        'custom' => [
            'class' => 'app\auth\CustomOAuth',
            'clientId' => 'clientIDHere',
            'clientSecret' => 'clientSecretHere',
        ],
    ],
],
```

In my base controller class I have added the following behavior:

```
public function behaviors() {

    $behaviors = parent::behaviors();
    $behaviors['authenticator'] = [
        'class' => HttpBearerAuth::className(),
    ];
    return $behaviors;
}
```

And then basically I'm at a loss as to what to put in the `findIdentityByAccessToken` function of my `IdentityInterface` class (which is what gets called when the HttpBearerAuth class tries to create the identity of the user) The `BaseOAuth` class will check it's own internal version of the OAuthToken before doing anything so there is no way for me to call the baseAPI of my AuthClient to check the token.

Is there a preferred way of handling this case where Yii2 just needs to check that a token is valid instead of actually exchanging the code for the token? Or do I just need to make a raw CURL call myself to the API?

Comment: But why are you attempting to add some kind of user functionality in your code if that is all handled via the AD? Do you need to know which user it is for some reason? It might just be me, but the question is not entirely clear.

Comment: Because the API needs to know that the user is authorized and that the token is still valid to serve them the resource.

Comment: I think there's too much things internal to this problem for people to be able to help you. But if only the validity of the token is important to you, I would personally not bother with the `HttpBearerAuth` approach and add a `beforeAction` function that validates the token directly and "fails" (false or access exception) if it's invalid. Saves you from having to implement "something `UserIdentity`"

Comment: I was following along the guidelines in the [Yii2 Rest Authentication Guide](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-rest-authentication.html). Seems weird that they only half fleshed this out which is why I thought I must have missed something.

Comment: That guide probably assumes you have a local User table in which you can perform your lookups, hence the `UserIdentity`-functionality. It doesn't work without. Normally you have a `token` field in that same table that houses the active token, for which the `findIdentityByAccessToken` is called.